# Добавление массива к другому массиву

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток нужна помощь есть массив:

```
$arr=array(
  [1]=>one,
  [2]=>array(
    array([0]=>1)
  )
);
```

как к массиву ключа [2] добавить ещё массив нужно именно к первому массиву ключа[2] добавить.

```
$arr=array(
  [1]=>one,
  [2]=>array(
    array([0]=>1)
    array([1]=>1)
  )
);
```

Только, пожалуйста, не пишите, что есть ошибка в синтаксисе, пример взят не из жизни. Реальный массив используется для wordpress. Интересует, возможно ли выбрать значение ключа 2 (именно по ключу) и добавить к нему ещё один массив.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array_push($arr[2],array('1'=>1));
```

либо

```
array_push($arr[2],array(count($arr[2])=>1));
```

ideone.com/RwjJi2

Comment: Огромное спасибо очень выручили